# Must Declare Scalar Variable Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

My syntax keeps giving me the below error, which is blowing my mind as I think (and please kindly correct me if I am incorrect), I have declared and set this variable above.

> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 1
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@id".

Here is my syntax, and if I include a `print @id` statement the proper value will be output, however I still get the above error?!

```
Create Table #temphold
(
  dateadded datetime
  ,dateupdated datetime
  ,id varchar(100)
)

Declare @id varchar(100), @sql varchar(max)
Set @id = '12345'


set @sql = 'insert into   #temphold(dateadded,dateupdated,id) '
          +'select   getdate(),getdate(),COALESCE(@id,'''') '
PRINT @SQL
EXEC(@SQL)


Drop Table #temphold
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@id as part of the execution variable @sql is doing nothing. It is not tied to the declared and set variable unless you build the string around it, i.e. concatenate it to the string like this:

`set @sql = 'insert into   #temphold(dateadded,dateupdated,id) '
          +'select   getdate(),getdate(),COALESCE(' + @id + ','''') '`

Notice the + either side of the @id variable.

At the end of the day, @sql is just a string until it's executed using the EXEC() command. Simply treat it as such until it compiles as fully qualified T-SQL.

Comment: Technically speaking, the `@id` variable inside `@sql` is in a different scope to the `declare @id` statement.  Hence SQL Server displays the error about `@id` not being declared.

Answer (score 3):

You can also pass `@id` in as a parameter to the dynamic query instead of putting it in as a literal. To do this you need to use the `sp_executesql` function instead of `EXEC`.  IMO passing parameters into the statement helps make the generated statement a little more clear/readable and you don't have to cast or convert certain data types into a `nvarchar` equivalent.  Doing it this way also gives you a better chance of SQL Server generating a query plan that it could reuse.

Here is a post on Stack Overflow that provides some compare and contrasts.  [Stored procedure EXEC vs sp_executesql difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14722201/stored-procedure-exec-vs-sp-executesql-difference)

Here is [Microsoft's technet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175170%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) article on `sp_executesql`

```
Create Table #temphold
(
  dateadded datetime
  ,dateupdated datetime
  ,id varchar(100)
)

Declare @id varchar(100), @sql nvarchar(max)
Set @id = '12345'


set @sql = 'insert into   #temphold(dateadded,dateupdated,id) '
          +'select   getdate(),getdate(),COALESCE(@id,'''') '
PRINT @SQL;
execute sp_executesql @statement = @sql, @parameters = N'@id varchar(100)', @id = @id

Drop Table #temphold
```

Comment: This is a useful tip and in terms of best practice is a better answer than mine, which merely fixed your code. sp_executesql is also more secure than working with literals from a SQL injection POV. From memory, it doesn't work with all parameters though. Table variables being one example. You can't pass them in. Horses for courses.

Answer (score 1):

The variable @sql **only** lives where it's defined. Definitions are delimited by a 'GO' statement. See if this works for you...

```
Set @id = '12345'
Set @sql = 'insert into   #temphold(dateadded,dateupdated,id) '
          +'select   getdate(),getdate(),COALESCE(@id,'''') '
GO
PRINT @sql;
execute sp_executesql @statement = @sql, @parameters = N'@id varchar(100)', @id = @id

Drop Table #temphold
```